# Magento Syslogger

Tags: log, devops, logging

I would like to publish Enterprise Admin logging and other event data to a syslog server, as well as custom logs, system, or exception log.

I know that Zend has a syslog logtype capability (`Zend_Log_Writer_Syslog`) - is anyone aware of a plugin or a set of best practices that come with publishing log data to a syslogger?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get email notifications for exceptions?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4886/how-can-i-get-email-notifications-for-exceptions) , see the answers there that offer a hackaton extension that can be modified to address this

Comment: We have already a syslogger included :D https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Logger

Comment: NICELY DONE. Make it an answer..

Comment: I contend that this isn't a duplicate - I don't want (or believe that it is proper) to email this type of information.

Comment: sure it's not but the solution is the same

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt, early bird gets the worm ;) I posted your answer.

Comment: @philwinkle, out of curiosity, why is it you don't think it's proper to email exception logs?  Just because email is generally not a very secure channel?

Comment: @kalenjordan correct. Email is fairly easy to snoop and exception logging via email exposes your store vulnerabilities to an insecure channel.

Comment: True.  I should probably do something more secure at some point.  I got the idea for email notifications with exception dumps in them from services like loggly.com - it's one of the more prominent features that they use.  Maybe an email notification with a link to the actual exception dump that required a login would be a lot better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module has support for syslogger:
https://github.com/magento-hackathon/Logger

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the Logger module above has been moved to https://github.com/firegento/firegento-logger since then.